# Glare node issue

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: The Glitch]

I have been experiencing strange glitches with the Glare node in the compositor. Frankly, I cannot quite figure out what causes it, since it seems to depend on randomness—frame, camera distance, the day of the week. I think that it is a glitch, but figured I would post an example here anyway in the off chance it is not.
Help would be appreciated, if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw render's pixel values?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue just on 1 frame. I solved it by changing the node quality from High to Medium.

Edit: happened on more frames and in different ways. Just solve it the Blender way, crank up those samples!

Comment: Ugh, the same thing happened to me like a month ago, so I wish I found this before spending 4 hours figuring it out!